# Can I extend my bonus from Fighting Defensively by delaying?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat

I have an initiative of 10 and do a [full-round defensive fighting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Fighting-Defensively-as-a-Full-Round-Action) to get +4 to by AC. My enemy has an initiative of 8. Next turn at initiative phase 10, I decide to delay my action to 7. At initiative phase 8, my enemy attacks. Do I get the +4 bonus to AC?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you fight defensively, it lasts “until the start of your next turn.”

But your next turn has to begin before you can choose to [Delay](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Delay), because it is an action. As a consequence, by the time you've had the opportunity to choose to delay, you've already lost the AC bonus.

Comment: I agree with this answer.  To add an element of IC understanding to the RAW:  Say you choose to delay in order to attack someone who attacks you.  Your stance shifts from a defensive stance to an aggressive one, waiting only for the enemy to draw near in order to unleash death - since your stance has now shifted, you are losing the +4 AC.  If you retained that defensive stance, then you would not be delaying - you would be performing another 'Full Round Defensive' action.

Comment: @WolfmanJoe You’re talking about Readying, not Delaying. Delay is literally just choosing to take your turn later, not preparing to do a specific thing (like attacking someone who attacks you).

Comment: @KRyan The description I gave can describe either.  You have to have SOME reason for wanting to wait for a later initiative ranking.  Whatever that reason is, you're readying yourself for it.  Or you're just getting yourself into forward-momentum mode, ready to do SOMETHING when the opportunity arises, but you're still getting ready to be *active*, and not just defensive.

Comment: Has a creature's turn really *started* if the creature picks to take its turn *later*? Although its an *action* to delay, it's a *special initiative action* that doesn't take one of the usual actions and, instead, only moves the creature down the initiative ladder, allowing no usual actions beforehand. It seems like the fighting defensively bonus should endure, because—if it being a special initiative action isn't enough—the creature is giving its foes a whole 'nother turn to defeat it.

Comment: @HeyICanChan The text of delay is all setting up permission to be able to act later, despite having just taken an action. Also, there's no provision for any non-turn way to take the Delay action; it relies on normal turn-taking to trigger, and then just edits your turn from the inside (voiding its content, basically) and creates an ersatz turn a bit later with explicit permission to act as normal at that point.